# When refactoring classes and methods why JDT doesn't change referenced resources?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-jdt

When refactoring classes and methods JDT doesn't change referenced resources, while it does when refactoring packages. I use the following code:

```
RefactoringContribution contrib = RefactoringCore.getRefactoringContribution(IJavaRefactorings.RENAME_COMPILATION_UNIT);
RenameJavaElementDescriptor desc =  (RenameJavaElementDescriptor)contrib.createDescriptor();
desc.setUpdateReferences(true);
desc.setJavaElement(classToRename);
desc.setNewName(newName);
Refactoring ref = desc.createRefactoring(new RefactoringStatus());
IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
Change change = refactoring.createChange(monitor);
change.perform(monitor);
```

an advice will help:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I investigated *JDT* thoroughly and came to the following conclusion:

1. The current *JDT* API has this maximum potential regarding classes and
   methods
2. It's difficult to change the references in case of classes and
   methods because they are not referenced like packages i.e.
   my.package.util is easy where MyClass has no reference and can be
   present in more than one package.

But it can be done coming out of the known java frameworks like *spring*, *hibernate* *iBatis* resource files if *JDT* developers would give some time to it, but it will be still a whole lot of work and time spending.
The solution is to refactor yourself through IO streams by putting replacement/change conditions, but also it will be a lot of work.